# Adding UiView to scroll view, works in simulator but not on iPhone X actual device

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is the code I use to add UIViews to a scroll view, it works fine in the simulator and all real devices except iPhone X. It does not load any data. I get this error in the logs 'Connection to daemon was invalidated'. I've tried to research my problem but I'm at a loss. Is there something with iPhone X or some privacy settings I'm missing, or is there something wrong with the code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
     - (void)GenerateLessonTable{
      int xcounter = 0;
      int longest = 0;
      NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
      [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
      
      //past appointments
      _LessonListRect.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
      
      for(NSDate *date in thisstudent.listofpastlessons){
       [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size;
        CGFloat
         x = 0.0,
         y = 0.0,
         w = 0.0,
         h = 0.0;
        
       if (result.width >= 0  && result.width <= 374){
           x   = 10.0;
           y   = 10.0;
           w   = 60.0;
           h   = 60.0;
                 
      } if (result.width >= 375  && result.width <= 413) {
          x   = 7.0;
          y   = 7.0;
          w   = 55.0;
          h   = 55.0;
                           
      }  if (result.width >= 414 && result.width <= 767) {
          x   = 10.0;
          y   = 10.0;
          w   = 60.0;
          h   = 60.0;
                                            
      }  if (result.width >= 768 && result.width <= 833) {
          x = 15;
          y = 10;
          w = 75;
          h = 75;
                                            
      }  if (result.width >= 834 && result.width <= 1023) {
          x = 15;
          y = 15;
          w = 80;
          h = 80;
                                                  
      }  if (result.width >= 1024) {
          x = 15;
          y = 15;
          w = 95;
          h = 95;
                                       
      }  if (result.width >= 1536) {
          x = 20;
          y = 20;
          w = 90;
          h = 90;
                                                
                                              }
      UIView *testview =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((xcounter*(x+w))+x, y, w,h)];
      UIView *labelrect = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y/5, w, h)];
      
       
    
       // border radius
       [testview.layer setCornerRadius:2.0f];
       // border
       [testview.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
       [testview.layer setBorderWidth:0.0f];
        testview.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x178BFF);  // blue color
     
       UILabel *testlabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:labelrect.bounds];
        testlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
        testlabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
        testlabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
       NSString *line1 = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
       [formatter setDateFormat:@"H:mm"];
       NSString *line2 = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
       testlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r%@",line1,line2];
       testlabel.numberOfLines = 0;
       [labelrect addSubview:testlabel];
       [testview addSubview:labelrect];
       [_LessonListRect addSubview:testview];
       
       xcounter = xcounter+1;
   }
```

Comment: Just eyeballing your code quickly shows me that you create testView in multiple places. Why not write the conditions so that you create the testview only once, it will make it a lot easier to debug and also to help/

Comment: @skaak Do you mean simplifying the 'if' statements? I will test a simple version and then put it up.

Comment: Can you run other apps (in debug, from Xcode) successfully on your `iPhone X`? Is this happening immediately, or does this app work fine *until* you get to this view controller? If you skip all of that code (either comment it out or `return;` as the first line in `GenerateLessonTable`) do you still get the `Connection to daemon was invalidated` error?

Comment: @DonMag I have a login screen, which works fine. You can login and the customer number and password are verified and it goes to the next view controller. Logs confirm bytes were received. However, the customer appointment data does not show and also I've tried to debug it but it seems that information from the class-JSON-NSdictionary is not loading at all. The ' Connection to Daemon ....' occurs even before login. I'm very lost by this because its only on iPhone X-actual that this happening.

Comment: @DonMag I'm quite new to this so I don't have many other apps to test with but I tried an extremely stripped down version and the same problem was occurring.

Comment: @skaak I'm sorry I'm still quite new to this. Can you provide a simple example at how I can simplify my code. I apologize for asking.

Comment: @skaak Well I cobbled it together from looking at StackOverflow posts and other sites. I can understand how the code works but I have very little experience. So most of what I do is trial and error.

Comment: @eigo - you commented *"information from the class-JSON-NSdictionary is not loading at all ... The ' Connection to Daemon ....' occurs even before login ... its only on iPhone X-actual that this happening."* Based on that description, the code you posted **has nothing to do with the problem**. You need to debug / step through your *earlier* code to find out when the `Connection to daemon...` issue is happening. Is this happening on ***every*** `iPhone X`? Or are you using only one physical iPhone X device?

Comment: @DonMag Unfortunately I can only test on one iPhone X, but I have tested it on iPhones  6s, 7, 8, XR, iPad 2nd Gen and they all work. Plus of course all the simulator iPhones and iPads. I will step through my code and try to find where its not working. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: CGRect also has x, y, width and height and there are built in functions to check if one rect is inside another eg. But for here I think your approach is best - but remember CGRect for future.